# dependent drop-down in odoo / open erp

Tags: drop-down-menu, selection, dependency-properties, openerp-7, odoo

I have  made two drop-downs. Second dropdown's data is dependent on first drop-down's chosen value.

I have tried multiple methods, but didn't find any relevant solution.

Those are my three lists:

```
SELECTION_LIST = (('sela','Selected a'),
                 ('selb','Selected b'))

SELECTION_LIST_2 = (('selc','Selected c'),
                   ('seld','Selected d'))

SELECTION_LIST_3 = (('sele','Selected e'),
                   ('self','Selected f'))
```

And I defined my fields this way:

```
'type_selection': fields.selection(
    [
        ('selection1', 'Selection 1'),
        ('selection2', 'Selection 2'),
        ('selection3', 'Selection 3'),
    ], 'Category 1', required=False),

'type_selection_2': fields.selection(
    type_selection={
        'selection1': [{SELECTION_LIST}],
        'selection2': [{SELECTION_LIST_2}],
        'selection3': [{SELECTION_LIST_3}],
    }, "Category 2", required=False)
```

Unfortunately I get an error.

Comment: What can be done in this . please help??

Answer (score 0):

Try by using domain with on_change() methods.

Answer (score 0):

@user32876

Incorrect syntax for second 'field.selection', it takes an array of tuple and you are trying to pass a dictionary, which is wrong. First one is correct. And you can use 'on_change' method to change the value of second dropdown based on the first dropdown selection.

Post your code for better understanding and explain what exactly you want to do.