# dependent drop-down list in odoo 8 / open erp

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, ubuntu-16.04, odoo-8

I have made two drop-down lists. Second drop-down list's data is dependent on first drop-down list's chosen value i.e it changes dynamically.
First DDL is **Region**  which contains **one or many Departments** that provide second *DDL.

I have tried multiple methods like [this one](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591360/dependent-drop-down-in-odoo-open-erp) but didn't find any relevant solution.

would somebody like help me?
*DDL = DropDownList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way and it's work nicely.

```
class Region(models.Model):
    _name = 'obertys.region'
     name = fields.Char(string=u'Region', required=True )

class Department(models.Model):
    _name = 'obertys.department'
     name = fields.Char(string=u'Departement')
     reg_id = fields.Many2one(store=True, string=u'Région',
                             comodel_name='obertys.region',)
```

After having put in relation region and departement, the whole is played at the level of the view (file xml). This piece of code below for illustration
`<group string="Lieux">
    <field name="reg" class="oe_inline"/>
    <field name="dept" domain="[('reg_id','=',reg)]" class="oe_inline"/>
 </group>`

PS: I also use region in other model by Many2one to have it in DDL